# Making two columns by skipping a string in Python?

Tags: python, file, txt, file-processing

For example, let's say I have a file called test.txt, the content is as follows, thousands of strings under each other.

```
I will come one day.
What did you do.
I will go home.
OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then.
I will come.
```

What I want is that the first two lines are written side by side. When they are written side by side, put the special character I want between them. So like this

```
I will come one day. ■What did you do?
I'll go home. ■Okay, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then. ■I'll come.
```

I need a code so that I can print them like this. I've been searching for exactly four hours, but I finally gave up and I'm going to sleep. Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: you said `What I want is that the first two lines are written side by side`, but in the example, you applied your method on the first 6 lignes? could you please make it clear?

Comment: Sorry, What I want is that  lines are written side by side. When they are written side by side, put the special character I want between them. So like this

Answer (score 0):

If your input line count is even, or it's fine if last one got lost with odd number of lines, try this:

```py
>>> with open("src.txt") as src, open("output.txt", "wt") as output:
...     while (line1 := src.readline()) and (line2 := src.readline()):
...         output.write(f"{line1.strip()} # {line2.strip()}\n")
```

src.txt:

```
I will comeone day.
What did you do.
I will go home.
OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then.
I will come.
```

output.txt:

```
I will comeone day. # What did you do.
I will go home. # OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then. # I will come.
```

---

Or if you need it to work with odd number too, try this:

```py
>>> with open("src.txt") as src, open("output.txt", "wt") as output:
...     while (line1 := src.readline()) and (line2 := src.readline()):
...         output.write(f"{line1.strip()} # {line2.strip()}\n")
...     if line1 and not line2:
...         output.write(line1)
```

src.txt:

```
I will comeone day.
What did you do.
I will go home.
OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then.
I will come.
Meow
```

output.txt:

```
I will comeone day. # What did you do.
I will go home. # OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then. # I will come.
Meow
```

This second one will throw error when there's only one line in text file, but since you said thousands, should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Prints all lines in the file with the special character in between

```py
special_char = "#"

with open("text.txt", "r") as txt:
    lines = txt.readlines() # read all lines in the file

lines = [line.strip("\n") for line in lines] # remove newline charactor from its end
n = len(lines) #find the number of lines

if n%2 == 0:  # if number of lines is even
    for i in range(0,n,2):  # go from 0 to n with 2 steps at a time, i.e, i = i+2
        print(f"{lines[i]} {special_char} {lines[i+1]}")

else:  # if number of lines is odd
    for i in range(0,n-1,2):
        print(f"{lines[i]} {special_char} {lines[i+1]}")
    print(lines[-1])  # print the last line in the list
```

Output:

Even number of lines

```
I will come one day. # What did you do.
I will go home. # OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then. # I will come.
```

Odd number of lines

```
I will come one day. # What did you do.
I will go home. # OK, I'll come too.
I'm waiting then. # I will come.
See you then
```